# sqlite3.g4 grammar does not handle left join correctly

Tags: antlr4

The github sqlite3 grammar github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sqlite/SQLite.g4 has issue with left join.

For this sql

```
select * from t1 left join t2 on t1.owner = t2.email
```

the word 'left' is parsed as a table_alias. Things go rapidly downhill from there

I think I can fix it by somehow saying that `table_alias` is `any_name` except K_LEFT, K_RIGHT, K_INNER but I do not know how to express that in a grammar

Or maybe there is a better way to fix this

UPDATE. Just to clarify sqlite behavior. (Not talking about antlr , talking about what sqlite understands)

this

```
select username from user left join device on device.owner = user.id limit 2
```

works.

This

```
select username from user alias join device on device.owner = user.id limit 2
```

fails saying that the column user.id doesn't exist.

Clearly the word 'left' is being recognized as a keyword not a table alias.

```
select username from user alias join device on device.owner = alias.id limit 2
```

Works, and does an inner join

```
select username from user alias left join device on device.owner = user.id limit 2
```

works and does a left join

Further update for @Mike Lischke

```
select username from user left where device.owner = left.id limit 2
```

Fails. `"Query has failed: near "where": syntax error".`

Comment: Are you writing the grammar from scratch ? Did you take a look at https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/sqlite/SQLite.g4 ?

Comment: that is the grammar i am referring to - updated the question

Comment: Silly question, but does that also happen when you use capitals for all the reserved keywords?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is correct. `LEFT` is included in the `keyword` rule which in turn is used in `any_name`, which is valid input for `table_alias` (this is known as the *keywords-as-identifiers* problem). Your query is wrong, according to the grammar, period. Any word following the table name is a table alias, regardless whether it is usually a keyword or not.

A workaround could be to add a validating predicate, which checks the following token and fails the `table_alias` rule if the current token is something that should be used in its original meaning. You can get the same result by removing the `LEFT` keyword from the `keyword` rule. However, that might have other side effects in places where you **want** the `LEFT` keyword to be valid input for an identifier.

Comment: well sqlite accepts the query and executes it as though it were a left join, not as a table alias (I cannot refer to the table by the name 'left', adding 'as' before the word 'left' makes it into an alias). I assume that it knows that several keywords are allowed after a tables name: as, left, right, inner and it checks those b4 it triggers the table alais rule

Comment: Can you have `LEFT` alone after the table name (i.e. without `JOIN`)?I believe the SQLite parser either changes the meaning of certain keywords depending on some condition (non-context-free parser) or these keywords are not allowed in such contexts like the table alias (and the grammar you use is wrong).

Comment: You didn't mention the case I asked for, e.g. `select username from user left where device.owner = left.id limit 2`. If `left` is allowed as normal identifier this will still work, making `left` the alias for `user`. If it fails it does probably for the incomplete `left join` phrase and it means the ANTLR4 grammar is wrong.

Comment: See updated question. TL;DR. That sql fails with syntax error

Comment: That's what I expected. `LEFT` alone is not allowed (which would if this keyword would really be allowed as identifier there). That means the g4 grammar is wrong. You have to change it. Just take out the few `JOIN` keywords from the `keywords` rule. You may have to create another similar rule which includes them for other rules.